# Remote ODBC connection to SAP SQL Anywhere 17

Tags: c#, .net, sqlanywhere

My question is: could anyone give me an example of working **connection string** to connect to SQL Anywhere 17 DB using **ODBC** without DSN?

I have already tried several connection strings found in Internet but no luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driver={SQL Anywhere 17};LINKS=TCPIP{HOST=localhost};ENG=demo17;DBN=demo;uid=DBA;pwd=sql